# Swing JTree how custom Render get value from custom Editor?

Tags: java, swing, customization, jtree, treecellrenderer

I try to make JTree with custom TreeRenderer

```
public class TextCellRender implements TreeCellRenderer {
    JPanel panel;
    JTextArea text;
    JLabel label;
    LayoutManager Layout;

    public TextCellRender() {
        text = new JTextArea();
        text.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        text.setLineWrap(true);
        text.setSize(360, text.getPreferredSize().height);
        label = new JLabel();
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(text);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, 
            boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf,
            int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        Component returnValue = null;
        if ((value != null) && (value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode)) {
            Object userObject = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject();
            if ((userObject instanceof FieldObj)) {
                FieldObj my = (FieldObj) userObject;
                String fieldText = "";

                text.setText(my.valueList);
                label.setText(my.FieldName);

            }
            return panel;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

and with custom Editor

```
public class TextCellEdit extends AbstractCellEditor implements TreeCellEditor {
```

Which getTreeCellEditorComponent return panel as getTreeCellEditorComponent but with JComboBox which Items populates from db.
Render and Editor work great I can click on field and comboBox shows with values from db.

```
public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(JTree tree, Object value, 
        boolean isSelected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row) {
    if (value != null && value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
        Object userObject = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject();
        if (userObject instanceof FieldObj) {
            FieldObj my = (FieldObj) userObject;
            box.removeAllItems();
            label.setText(my.FieldName);
            populatebox(my.FieldName);
            box.addItem(my.valueList);
            panel.add(label);
            panel.add(box);
        } else {
            box.addItem("Uknown object type");
        }
        return panel;
    }
}
public Object getCellEditorValue() { 
    System.out.println("getCellEditoValue returns :" + box.getSelectedItem());
    return box.getSelectedItem();
}
```

But it doesn't save in Render textArea
I mean in Render I have panel with:
JLabel (FieldName)
JTextArea (FieldValue)

when I click on JTextArea I have my Editor which has:
JLabel (FieldName)
JComboBox(FieldValues which I have populated from db)

but when I chose something from Edit ComboBox it doesn't save in Render TextArea
So the question is how this things should work?

**How render component get value from Edit component?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you implement **TreeCellEditor** you must to override `public Object getCellEditorValue()` method. That method calls when you cancel/exit from editing. In this method you can save your new value to object that you store in TreeNode. Then your **Renderer** got edited object with new value in `getTreeCellRendererComponent` method.

EDIT: Your editor be like that :

```
public class TextCellEdit extends AbstractCellEditor implements TreeCellEditor {

private JComboBox<Object> box;
private JLabel label;
private JPanel panel;
private FieldObj my;

public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row) {

    if (value != null && value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
        Object userObject = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value)
                .getUserObject();
        if (userObject instanceof FieldObj) {
            my = (FieldObj) userObject;
            box.removeAllItems();
            label.setText(my.FieldName);
            populatebox(my.FieldName);
            box.addItem(my.valueList);
            panel.add(label);
            panel.add(box);
        } else {
            box.addItem("Uknown object type");
        }
        return panel;
    }
}

public Object getCellEditorValue() { 
    System.out.println("getCellEditoValue returns :" + box.getSelectedItem());
    my.FieldName = box.getSelectedItem();
    return box.getSelectedItem();
}
}
```

Comment: that is not quite true getCellEditorValue() is invoken when i editor component is change but i can't find where Render use it.
(I have implemented this method , seems to me it needs for things like validation or other when u need to get changed value) 
Seems that Render use some Listeners but now i can't find it out.

Comment: It isn't used by Renderer. It only change your object. Renderer read object again and catch changes. EDIT: Renderer in `getTreeCellRendererComponent` always get changed object and shows it.

Comment: thanks for you help.
I edit my question (add getCellEditorValue implementation) could u tell what wrong in it pleace
it try return box.getSelectedItem().toString() to just for case.
first i was think that Render get value but can set it because i return panel , i try return just TextArea from Render, the same result.
Also i can't find a good explanation of getCellEditorValue().