# creating a right- click menu pop-up on a jTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I want to create a jTree which when i right click on a node, should give me the options of "rename","add Region(parent)","add City(child)".

the name of my jTree is branches

As i am new to swing,Could any one help with code. Thanks in Advance.

Regards, Sarkwa

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to use `setComponentPopupMenu` method of `JTree` with `MouseListener`. In mouseListener determine Node for menu and generate popupMenu once. I write a simple example which can help you to do your work.

```
public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private JTree t;
private DefaultTreeModel model;
private DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode;

public Main() {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode n = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("test");
    n.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("test2"));
    model = new DefaultTreeModel(n);
    t = new JTree(model);
    t.setEditable(true);
    t.setComponentPopupMenu(getPopUpMenu());
    t.addMouseListener(getMouseListener());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().add(t);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

private MouseListener getMouseListener() {
    return new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            if(arg0.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3){
                TreePath pathForLocation = t.getPathForLocation(arg0.getPoint().x, arg0.getPoint().y);
                if(pathForLocation != null){
                    selectedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) pathForLocation.getLastPathComponent();
                } else{
                    selectedNode = null;
                }

            }
            super.mousePressed(arg0);
        }
    };
}

private JPopupMenu getPopUpMenu() {
    JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
    JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("edit");
    item.addActionListener(getEditActionListener());
    menu.add(item);

    JMenuItem item2 = new JMenuItem("add");
    item2.addActionListener(getAddActionListener());
    menu.add(item2);

    return menu;
}

private ActionListener getAddActionListener() {
    return new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(selectedNode != null){
                System.out.println("pressed" + selectedNode);
                DefaultMutableTreeNode n = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("added");
                selectedNode.add(n);
                t.repaint();
                t.updateUI();
            }
        }
    };
}

private ActionListener getEditActionListener() {
    return new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(selectedNode != null){
                //edit here
                System.out.println("pressed" + selectedNode);
            }
        }
    };
}

public static void main(String... s){
    new Main();
}

}
```

`getPopUpMenu` method generate your popUp. For all items in popUp I add Listener for actions.  For renaming nodes I recommend you to use `CellEditor` instead of menu, i write simple example of using it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706120/swing-jtree-how-custom-render-get-value-from-custom-editor/19706859#19706859).

And read this [tutorial for `JTree`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

- Add a `MouseListner` to the `JTree`
- Have the mouse listener only respond to events from Button3 (right click).
- Have the listner's action display a `JPopupMenu`.
- In the menu add your options
- Your options will have actions that will need to have a reference back to the `JTree` for the appropriate modifications to happen.

Comment: can u pls give me an example of how this is done? will appreciate that

Comment: Which step?  It sounds like you need to read some of the Swing Tutorials they have plenty of examples.